# Throwned Error cannot be handled in createReadStream in Node.js using express-js

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, fs, throw

I'm trying to handle an exception thrown in an fs.createReadStream, and I use a Promise for that, but the error terminates the API, despite the .catch.

What am I doing wrong ?

Here is my test code :

```js
fcts = require('./functions.js');

app.get('/test', function(req, res){
    console.log("OK TEST")
    fcts.test(req, res, '/data/file')
    .then(result => console.log("OK"))
    .catch(err => console.log("NO"))
})
```

```js
module.exports = {
    test: function (request, response, fichier){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var flux = fs.createReadStream(fichier)
            .on('error', function(err){
                console.log("no")
                reject("reject")
            })
            .on('close', function(){
                console.log("end")
                resolve("ok")
            })
            .pipe(unzip.Parse())
            .on('entry', function (entry) {
                throw("uh")
            });
            console.log("end end")
        })
    }
}
```

Here are my logs:

```sh
...
OK TEST
end end

.../functions.js:1493
                        throw("uh")
                        ^
uh
```

I am using node 8.16.0 and express-js

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work if you reject instead of throwing :

```js
.on('entry', function (entry) {
     reject(new Error('uh'));
});
```

Throwing in a callback used by an async function inside a Promise definition function will not work, because the context in wich it have been thrown is not the promise one, but the one of the `createReadStream` that don't seems to trigger the `error` event for an exception thrown in a callback you defined with `on`.

In fact, in your case, the error that is thrown is an `UncaughtException`, because the context in wich the error occurs doesn't catch it. Since it is in an asynchronous context, it's the node.js context that notice the error.

Why ? Maybe because the `error` event in only triggered for stream errors, not for callback executions failures.

When running your script in nodejs, you should use the flag --trace-uncaught `nodejs --trace-uncaught ./myfile.js`. it will prompt you more infos on uncaught exceptions when it occurs.